# PHP prepend an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

By using the PHP below outputs the values underneath. But because I don't have control of the API output I would like to try and prepend the data with another output such as `{"id":0,"name":"Begin","description":"this is my description","url":"http://domain.com"}`

Could someone please help?

**PHP**

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "/api/styles";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);

echo $json;
?>
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Pale","description":"this is my description","url":"http://domain.com"},{"id":2,"name":"Dawn","description":"this is my description","url":"http://domain.com"}]
```

Comment: This is json, not a PHP array. Is it supposed to be converted into a PHP array, or do you just want to prepend your own json to the json from the API?

Comment: @jd182 I'd like to add that json to the front of the printed

Comment: As I understand, you want to prepend your data in order to "sanitize" to some extent the output of the API you can't control, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
<?php
$jsonurl = "/api/styles";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$json = '[{"id":0,"name":"Begin","description":"this is my description","url":"http://domain.com"},' . substr($json, 1);
echo $json;
?>
```

Output:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"Begin","description":"this is my description","url":"http://domain.com"},{"id":1,"name":"Pale","description":"this is my description","url":"http://domain.com"},{"id":2,"name":"Dawn","description":"this is my description","url":"http://domain.com"}]
```

Comment: The OPs title is misleading. This is simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonurl = "/api/styles";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$begin = '{"id":0,"name":"Begin","description":"this is my description","url":"http://domain.com"}';

$data = json_decode($json);
array_unshift($data, json_decode($begin));

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it really is json, parse it (decode_json()) and print it anyway you like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly certain what you're wanting to "prepend" but you can turn it into a PHP array, reverse it then push new elements onto the array.

```
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$reversed = array_reverse( $array );
$reversed[] = ['id' => 0, 'name' => 'Something];
```

Reverse it back and encode it.